# CollectionViewSource View binding does not work for custom control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Hello I have written small program in MVVM fashion to test usage of CollectionViewSource. I have a UserControl that contains ListBox and has Dependency Property Items, which "forwards" binding items from this control to ListBox ItemsSource:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestingCollectionViewSource.TestControlWithListBox"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:TestingCollectionViewSource="clr-namespace:TestingCollectionViewSource" 
                mc:Ignorable="d" 
                d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
       <Grid>
           <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items,
           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TestingCollectionViewSource:TestControlWithListBox}}" />
       </Grid>
   </UserControl>


public partial class TestControlWithListBox : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof (IEnumerable<string>), typeof (TestControlWithListBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable<string>)));

        public IEnumerable<string> Items
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable<string>) GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
        }

        public TestControlWithListBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

I tried binding to Items with ObservableCollection and with View of CollectionViewSource.
It deos work for ObservableCollection but does not for CollectionViewSource.

```
<Window x:Class="TestingCollectionViewSource.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:TestingCollectionViewSource="clr-namespace:TestingCollectionViewSource" Width="500" Height="500">
    <Grid>
        <TestingCollectionViewSource:TestControlWithListBox Items="{Binding Path=ItemsCollectionViewSource.View}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public class MainWindowViewModel : Screen
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> items;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
        }
    }

    private CollectionViewSource itemsCollectionViewSource;

    public CollectionViewSource ItemsCollectionViewSource
    {
        get { return itemsCollectionViewSource; }
        set
        {
            itemsCollectionViewSource = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ItemsCollectionViewSource);
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        DisplayName = "Testing testing testing";
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>()
            {
                "1",
                "2 2",
                "3 3 3",
                "4 4 4 4"
            };

        ItemsCollectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = Items};
    }
}
```

However if I would try to bind CollectionViewSource.View to ListBox there is no problem and all list items are included in ListBox like in the picture below:

[image: CollectionViewSource Test]

What could be the reason of this behaviour and is there any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For binding to work, source property and target property should be of same data types.**

If you closely look at your Output window, you will see binding error logged over there for mismatch data types of source and target property.

---

`CollectionViewSource.View` property is of type `ICollectionView` which inherits from `IEnumerable` and not from `IEnumerable<string>`. Hence, source property type is `IEnumerable`, whereas your `Items` DP is of type `IEnumerable<string>`. Hence, its not working.

Whereas it works for `ObservableCollection<string>` because it implements both `IEnumerable<string>` and `IEnumerable`.

As evident from above that all list directly or indirectly implements `IEnumerable`. So, what you can do is make your `Items` DP of type IEnumerable instead of `IEnumerable<string>` and it will work for CollectionViewSource as well.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof (IEnumerable),
    typeof (TestControlWithListBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable)));

public IEnumerable<string> Items
{
   get { return (IEnumerable) GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
   set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works and now it's so obvious :-).